# Error en sobrecarga del operador de igualdad

Tags: python, comparaciones, operador, sobrecarga

Tengo el siguiente error en mi código:

> ```
> Exception has occurred: AttributeError
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_Conjunto__lista'
> ```

Problema es el siguiente:

Necesito comparar si 2 conjuntos de números enteros son iguales, la llamada se hace en la siguiente función:

```
def opcion3():        
    print("")
    print("*** IGUALDAD DE CONJUNTOS ***")
    print("*** CONJUNTO 1 ***")
    lon=input("Igrese la cantidad de elementos del conjunto: ")
    c1=Conjunto(0)
    try:
        lon=int(lon)
        c1.AgregaCjto(lon)
        os.system('cls')
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingresar un numero entero.")
    print("*** CONJUNTO 2 ***")
    lon=input("Igrese la cantidad de elementos del conjunto: ")
    c2=Conjunto(0)
    try:
        lon=int(lon)
        c2.AgregaCjto(lon)
        os.system('cls')
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingresar un numero entero.")
    print("Conjunto 1:")
    c1.Mostrar()
    print("Conjunto 2:")
    c2.Mostrar()
    if(c1!=None and c2!=None):
        c3 = c1==c2             #Sobrecarga del operador "=="
        print("La igualdad de los conjuntos es: {}".format(c3))
        gc.collect()
        del c1,c2
    else: print("No se ha podido realizar la operacion.")
```

Luego, el método que se ejecuta en la asignación `c3= c1==c2` es:

```
def __eq__(self,cjto):
    q=False
    self.__lista.sort()
    cjto.__lista.sort()                 #Linea del error

    if((len(self.__lista))==(len(cjto.__lista))):
        i=0
        for i in range(len(self.__lista)):
            if(self.__lista[i]==cjto.__lista[i]):
                q=True
            else:
                q=False
    else:
        q=False

    return q
```

al momento de utilizar el objeto que recibe como parámetro el método `__eq__` me devuelve el error, el objeto llega como `None`. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error viene de la línea:

```
if(c1!=None and c2!=None):
```

que también usa el método `__eq__` ante la no implementación de `__ne__` en la clase `Conjunto`. Pero obviamente el segundo operando es `None` y `None` no tiene un atributo `__list`...

Primero aclarar que hacer `c1!=None`  es incorrecto realmente en Python, `None` es un singleton como `True` y `False`, la forma correcta es usar el operador de identidad `is` para saber si un objeto cualquiera es o no `None`, debería ser:

```
if c1 is not None and c2 is not None:
    # ....
```

Dicho ésto, `__eq__` debería comprobar que el segundo operando  es también un objeto de `Conjunto`, de una clase que herede de ella u otro objeto que pueda ser comparado con el mismo, antes de intentar comprobar la igualdad y en especial antes de acceder al atributo `__list`. Si no haces ésto, cualquier comparación con un objeto que no implemente el atributo  (`Conjunto(0) == [4]`, `Conjunto(0) == {3}`, etc) resultará en un `AtributeError`.

Además `__eq__` no debería tener en principio efectos colaterales sobre los atributos, como aplicar `sort` que actúa in place, deberías usar `sorted` si no está asegurado que la lista esté ordenada, el ordenamiento de `__lista` debería hacerse en el método encargado de agregar items al conjunto.

Por último, la forma de comprobar que ambas listas son iguales es incorrecta:

```
if(self.__lista[i]==cjto.__lista[i]):
    q=True
else:
    q=False
```

Al usar un `if -else` y reasignar a `q` en todas las iteraciones en la práctica solo terminas comprobando si el último item de ambas es igual. Además deberías por eficiencia incluir un cortocircuito, debería ser:

```
q = False
# ...

if len(self.__lista) == len(cjto.__lista):
    for i in range(len(self.__lista)):
        if(self.__lista[i] != cjto.__lista[i]):
            break
    else:  # for completado sin break
        q = True
return q
```

o mejor usa `zip` y un iterador:

```
if len(self.__lista) == len(cjto.__lista):
    for a, b in zip(self.__lista, cjto.__lista):
        if a != b:
            break
    else:
        return True
 return False
```

o mejor aún usa `all` o `any` con un generador:

```
if len(self.__lista)) == len(cjto.__lista):
    return all(a == b for a, b in zip(self.__lista, cjto.__lista))
return False
```

No obstante, no tiene sentido que te compliques para ver si ambas listas son iguales, es mucho más simple y eficiente delegar en el método `__eq__` de `list` (implementado en C) , dos listas se consideran iguales si, y solo si, tienen la misma longitud y los mismos items en el mismo orden, que es precisamente los que buscas comprobar. el método finalmente debería quedar algo así:

```
def __eq__(self, cjto):
    if not isinstance(cjto, self.__class__):
        return False
    return sorted(self.__lista) == sorted(cjto.__lista)
```

Ahora ya no necesitas comprobar si alguno de los objetos es `None`:

```
print(f"La igualdad de los conjuntos es: {c1 == c2}")
```